# Not able to access component in code behind by component name

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mobile, maui

I am trying to access the collection view's with the name in code behind which is the child of the another collection view but the children collection view's is not recognized in code behind.

This is my xaml code in which I trying to access one collection view inside another one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Internal_SME_UI.Views.FlyoutMenuPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Internal_SME_UI.Helpers"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:SME_Data.Models;assembly=SME_Data"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Internal_SME_UI.ViewModels"
    Title="FlyoutMenuPage"
    x:DataType="vm:FlyoutMenuViewModel">

    <StackLayout
        Margin="10,20"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Spacing="10"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <CollectionView
            x:Name="collectionViewFlyout"
            Margin="3,15,5,15"
            x:FieldModifier="public"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FlyoutItems}"
            SelectionChanged="collectionViewFlyout_SelectionChanged"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="subMenuItems" x:DataType="models:FlyoutItemModel">

                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,auto">
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="5,10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label
                                x:Name="iconLbl"
                                FontFamily="Icon"
                                FontSize="16"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="{Binding MenuIcon}"
                                TextColor="#00416d" />
                            <Label
                                x:Name="titleLbl"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="10,0"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="16"
                                Text="{Binding Title}"
                                TextColor="#00416d" />

                        </Grid>
                        <CollectionView
                            x:Name="subMenuItemsCollectionView"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            x:FieldModifier="public"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}"
                            SelectionChanged="subMenuItemsCollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                            SelectionMode="Single">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:Name="subMenuItems" x:DataType="models:FlyoutItemModel">

                                    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0" Padding="5,10">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label
                                            x:Name="iconLblSubMenu"
                                            FontFamily="Icon"
                                            FontSize="16"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Text="{Binding MenuIcon}"
                                            TextColor="#00416d" />
                                        <Label
                                            x:Name="titleLblSubMenu"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Margin="10,0"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="16"
                                            Text="{Binding Title}"
                                            TextColor="#00416d" />

                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#00416d" />
                                                        <Setter TargetName="titleLblSubMenu" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White" />
                                                        <Setter TargetName="iconLblSubMenu" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Grid>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#00416d" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="titleLbl" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="iconLbl" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>

            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>


    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is my code behind in which **collectionViewFlyout** is recognized but collection view with name **subMenuItemsCollectionView** is not able to recognized and gives error in last line of this code.

```
using Internal_SME_UI.ViewModels;
using SME_Data.Models;

namespace Internal_SME_UI.Views;

public partial class FlyoutMenuPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly FlyoutMenuViewModel _flyoutMenuViewModel;
    public FlyoutMenuPage(FlyoutMenuViewModel flyoutMenuViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _flyoutMenuViewModel = flyoutMenuViewModel;
        BindingContext = flyoutMenuViewModel;
        collectionViewFlyout.SelectedItem = flyoutMenuViewModel.FlyoutItems[1];
        

    }
    public FlyoutMenuPage():this(new FlyoutMenuViewModel()) { }

    private void collectionViewFlyout_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() is FlyoutItemModel selectedItem)
        {
            if (selectedItem == _flyoutMenuViewModel.FlyoutItems[5])
            {
                collectionViewFlyout.SelectedItem = e.PreviousSelection;    
            }
        }
    }

    private void subMenuItemsCollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        collectionViewFlyout.SelectedItem = null;
        subMenuItemsCollectionView.SelectedItem = e.CurrentSelection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally don't recommend using `CollectionView` inside of `CollectionView`, which can cause all sorts of problems.

You can replace the inner `CollectionView` with [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-8.0).

And we don't usually use `x:Name` to access the controls in the `CollectionView`. You can use databinding instead.

For this, you can refer thread: [Add Button in DataTemplate in CollectionView .netMaui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74933684/add-button-in-datatemplate-in-collectionview-netmaui).